# Webpack config for publishing vue component into an npm package

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-component

here's my main js code for the component

```
import './sass/main.scss'
import Vlider from './Vlider.vue'

function install(Vue) {
    if (install.installed) return;
    install.installed = true;
    Vue.component('vlider', Vlider);
}

const plugin = {
    install,
};

let GlobalVue = null;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = window.Vue;
} else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = global.Vue;
}
if (GlobalVue) {
    GlobalVue.use(plugin);
}

Vlider.install = install;

export default Vlider
```

can anyone help me with the webpack config? I need to output 4 files from this index.js

1. dist/vlider.umd.js
2. dist/vlider.esm.js
3. dist/vlider.min.js
4. vlider.css

so that it can support multiple entry points in `package.json`

```
"main": "dist/vlider.umd.js",
"module": "dist/vlider.esm.js",
"unpkg": "dist/vlider.min.js",
"browser": "src/vlider.vue"
```

this is my first time dealing with webpack so your help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack does not support `esmodule` as the output target. You can create `commonjs` module or `umd/iife` module.

If you need `ESModule` as a target then consider using **Rollup.js**. In general, you should use **Rollup** when you need to bundle library and **Webpack** for application bundling. *(Note: Rollup is great but TypeScript + .Vue files + Class-based vue component syntax does not work.)*

Also, irrespective of Webpack or Rollup, you can use array-based/multiple-targets export. Refer following links for more details:

Webpack: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#multiple-targets

Rollup: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#configuration-files

Comment: thanks for your answer, ill try to make my own config first for rollup, if I'm stuck again I'm gonna ask it here if you don't mind

Comment: @KawishBehzad That should be fine. As a good practice, update your original question than using a comment with code snippets.